# In native Javascript (or NodeJS) is it possible to chain object or function properties for a function call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, properties

More of an exercise in 'what-if', I was wondering if the following was possible:

```
output = convert(1200).from('mm').to('inches')
```

where 'from' and 'to' are functions (or properties) of 'convert' as opposed to the more standard:

```
    output = convert(1200, 'mm', 'inches')

or:

    output = convert(value = 1200, from = 'mm', to = 'inches')
```

**addendum**:  I'm guessing the closest would be:

```
output = convert({ value: 1200, from: 'mm', to: 'inches' });
 
function convert({ value, from, to } = {}){
  // ...do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: If `convert` returns an object that has a `from` method which returns an object that has a `to` method, sure. This is sometimes referred to as a _"fluent interface"_.

Comment: There is a lot of examples of libraries that use this method chaining for better readability

Comment: Understood, but my question does say 'native Javascript'.  :)

Comment: What JS would you consider to be native, or not native? Objects and methods are inherent functionality of JS, this should work everywhere

Comment: @thedigitalmouse: You can write a function in "native JavaScript" which returns an object which itself has a function.  It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: You can write your own code to do it. The return value of a function is whatever it is, according to how the function is written. Thus properties of the function object itself will usually not have anything to do with its return value unless it is written explicitly to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Example:

```js
function convert(val) {
  const units = {
    mm: 1,
    cm: 10,
    dm: 100,
    m: 1000,
    in: 25.4,
    inches: 25.4,
    inch: 25.4,
    ft: 304.8,
    feet: 304.8,
    foot: 304.8,
    yd: 914.4,
    yard: 914.4,
    yards: 914.4
  }
  return {
    from(unit1) {
      return {
        to(unit2) {
          return val * units[unit1] / units[unit2];
        }
      };
    }
  };
}

const output = convert(1200).from('mm').to('inches');

console.log(output);

console.log(convert(47.24409448818898).from('inches').to('mm'));
console.log(convert(123).from('m').to('yards'));
```

`convert` returns an object with a `from` method. `from` returns an object with a `to` method. `to` returns a number. The temporary values are stored in a closure.

Comment: This looks to be the best idea so far.  I just need to include other measurement systems such as weight (lbs, kgs, etc.) and volume (liters, gallons, f.ex.).  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @thedigitalmouse `units` could contain objects instead of values. Each object has a value and a category. If categories of two units mismatch, throw an error. `const units = { mm: { category: 'length', value: 1 }, kgs: { category: 'weight', value: 1000 } };`

Answer (score 1):

Create an object constructor with the convert, from and to functions, and properties to store the values passed to each corresponding function when called. In both `convert` and `from` functions, return the instance via 'return this' and return the answer in the `to` function.

https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_object_constructors.asp

```
function Converter() {
  this.value = 0;
  this.fromUnit = '';
  this.toUnit = '';
  this.convert = function(value) {
   ... 
   return this
  } 
 this.from = function(unit) {... return this} 
 this.to = function(unit) {... return answer} 
}

const converter = new Converter()
converter.convert(...).from(...).to(...)
```

You can also follow the Class syntax on ES6 JavaScript.
https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_classes.asp

Comment: Basicly yes, but this way `to` would return an unexpected value ..?

Comment: what do you mean by unexpected value?

Comment: You would expect `to` to return the converted value, but getting an object instead.

Comment: You're correct, you can return this only in convert and from, and return the answer in to. Good point!

Comment: Interesting approach.  Might get bulky trying to do multiple measurement systems such as weight and volume.  But that probably could be defined in the convert and made available to the to and from. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Treating this as a syntax rather than a design question, here is an ugly but working solution.

However, I would like to encourage you to refactor it or reconsider whether this functional API is necessary.

```js
const convert = (num) => ({
  from: (inputUnit) => {
    switch (inputUnit) {
      case "mm":
        return {
          to: (outputUnit) => {
            switch (outputUnit) {
              case "inches":
                return num / 25.4;
            }
          },
        };
    }
  },
});

console.log(
  convert(1200).from("mm").to("inches")
)
```

Comment: interesting, but yes quite unworkable when scaled up.  But thanks for your input.